# What is a "lemus"?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, british-english

Here's a fragment from "The Complete Fursey" by Mervyn Wall:

> *Other religious settlements were sadly plagued by disembodied spirits, demons, **lemuses** and fauns snorting and snuffling most fiendishly in the darker corners of the corridors and cells*.

What are "lemuses"?

Comment: Could be *lemures*: Beings similar to Caballi.http://www.primitivism.com/sexual.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably just a typo for [lemures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemures).

Comment: Or possibly, since Latin _lemures_ would likely be _lemus_ in the singular (though the singular is not attested, as far as I know), not a typo but a simple English pluralisation of a backformed word.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "A.R. Dunkel, J.S. Zijlstra, and C.P. Groves, C.P. (2011/2012). "Giant Rabbits, Marmosets, and British Comedies: Etymology of **Lemur** Names, part 1" **Lemur** News 16 (2100/12) 64–70. ISSN 1608-1439."  *op. cit.*

Comment: @Kris What does that have to do with anything? That seems to be about lemurs (the animals), which were named by Linnaeus by backforming a singular from _lemures_ in Latin as well. The Latin plural is ambiguous—it could have a singular _lemus_ or it could have a singular _lemur_. So where Linnaeus backformed _lemur_, Wall may have backformed _lemus_; neither would be any more ‘correct’ than the other.

Comment: Your theory does require an pretty exact combination of expertise and illiteracy, you need one guy to know that the singular of _lemures_ could be either _lemur_ or _lemus_, but never heard or Linnaeus, Goethe, or the little monkey-things, and then another guy to see _lemus_ and know what the first guy meant, but not know how to pluralize it.  Occam's Razor says: typo.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Why does one have to "backform" a singular from a plural, fun? Btw, what is *backform "backformed" out of? (note the asterisk.)

Comment: @Kris If the plural is the only form known, and you need to use a singular, then you basically have little choice but to backform one. And ‘backform’ is backformed from ‘backformation’, of course.

Comment: @Malvolio I think you misunderstood me. I meant that Wall may have been aware of the _lemures_ and of Linnaeus’ backformation, and for that exact reason (to avoid making it sound like little monkeys) chose to backform his own _lemus_ to refer specifically to ghost-like things akin to the Roman _lemures_; but giving it a regular English plural to avoid it sounding like he was talking about the actual Roman ones. Kind of like how _demons_ are a more generic term (with an English plural) than _daimones_ (with the Greek plural). But don’t know the text/Wall, so I don’t know. Just a possibility.

Comment: Ah, you are saying the whole thing might have been a deliberate choice by Wall to generate a new spelling, free of any association with the (somewhat ridiculous) primate? Not impossible, but since the word _lemuses_ is never used again in the book (and the singular _lemus_ does not appear at all), it becomes less likely.

Answer (score -2):

Since the Wall's *Fursey* books were fantasy (and fantasy/comedy at that), and the other creatures mentioned in the sentence are fantastic creatures, a lemus is almost certainly a creature of Wall's imagination.

There is also a possibility that a lemus is a creature of folk tales local to Dublin during the early 1900's when Wall was a child.

Since classically fauns http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faun were forest spirits, having them snorting and snuffling in the corners of monks' cells doesn't make a great deal of sense. So I'd advise you not to look to closely at the details of Wall's work - or at least don't worry too much about the minor characters.

Comment: Well no.  It's a typo.

Comment: @JoeBlow - Spirits aren't real. Demons aren't real. Fauns aren't real. So why do you think lemuses are a typo? What sort of imaginary being is lemuses a typo *for*? If you cannot provide a credible justification for your claim, please remove the downvote.

Comment: It's a typo. Read some of the source if don't believe.  I actually didn't downvote.  Note FWIW that votes mean utterly nothing on this site one way or the other, they are totally irrational.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast -- "lemuses" is a typo for *lemures* ("spirits of the restless or malignant dead").